# Can't adapt the screen to heigth 100%

Tags: html, css

I have a small problem,

I want my HTML code to be 100% height, but I can't get it to work.

This is a picture of my screen

[image]

My HTML code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" ng-app="zozoApp">
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>zozo</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel='stylesheet AdministrationUtilisateur' href='dev/vitrine/CSS/CerpStyle.css'>
     <style>


    html {
        height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        min-height: 100%;
    }


    /*footer*/
    .lienfooter{
        color: #91003e;
        text-decoration-line: underline;

    }
    .Gazano{
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration-line: none;

    }

    .lienfooter:hover{
        color: white;
        text-decoration-line: none;
    }

    .footer{
        height: 75px;
        background-color: #080808;
        padding-top: 2%;

    }

    /*End footer*/


    /*NavBar*/

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
        /*color: #8ABD24;*/
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: black
    }
    .navbar-default{
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9) !important;
        background-image: none;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    }

    .navbar{
        min-height: 91px;
    }

    .navbar-right {
        float: right !important;
        margin-right: -15px;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a span.line {
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(183,183,183,0) 13%,rgba(183,183,183,0.6) 50%,rgba(183,183,183,0) 87%);
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 1px;
        height: 40%;
        top: 30%;
        right: 0;
    }

    /*end navbar*/


</style>
</head>
<body>


<div id="NavbarT" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="#" title="">
                <img id="logo" style="max-width:171px; margin-top: -10px;margin-left:70px;" src="dev/vitrine/dd/Cerp_astera_couleur.png">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
            <div class="navbar-form navbar-right" ng-if="userCerp" >
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="d"><a href="#" id="Utilisateur" ui-sref="produit" data-dir="">Accueil<span class="line"></span></a></li>

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a href="#" id="Utilisateur" ui-sref="panier" data-dir=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"><lavel id="cart-badge" class="badge badge-warning"></lavel></span></a><span class="line"></span>
                        <div id="PopupPanier" class="dropdown-menue" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink" style="text-align: center">
                            <span id="textPopupPanier"   data-dir=""></span>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="NomClientNav">nom utilisateur</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu colordropdown" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <a class="textdeco" ng-click="Logoff()" style="cursor: pointer" id="logoff" data-dir="">deconnection</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div ui-view></div>

    <div id="footer" class="footer">
        <table width="100%" style="font-size: 12px;">
            <tr>
                <td width="33%" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 15px;"><a class="lienfooter" href="http://www.cerp.be/PUB/CRP990.aspx#CGU">Mentions légales</a></td>
                <td width="33%"  style="text-align: center"><p class="Gazano"> © <?php echo Date('Y'); ?> by zozo</p></td>
                <td width="33%"  style="text-align: right; padding-right: 15px;" ><a class="lienfooter" href="http://www.cerp.be/PUB/CRP990.aspx#CGV">Conditions générales</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I just want to fill out the white space and put the footer at the bottom for every screen

I already test HTML and body height 100% but Nothing worked

Comment: Your body is 100%. It's just the footer is not at the bottom of your body.

Comment: thanks but so how do i put the footer at the bottom ?

Comment: Try looking up "Sticky Footers" - it's the term for a footer that is at the bottom of the page, but in the event the page isn't tall enough, it sticks to the bottom of the browser window instead. There are quite a few ways to do this using negative margins and pseudo-elements, which is nice because you don't have to worry about positional overlap etc.

Comment: thanks for your help it works :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the footer `position:absolute` and add `position:relative` to the body. It also helps to add `padding-bottom` to the body for the height of the footer.

```
body{
    position: relative;
    /* padding-bottom: the height of the footer */
}
.footer{
    height: 75px;
    background-color: #080808;
    padding-top: 2%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you have a copy/paste issue in your code. I went ahead and edited it, sorry if I was wrong about your intent (I based it off your opening sentence).

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
.footer{
      height: 75px;
      background-color: #080808;
      padding-top: 2%;
      position:relative;
      bottom:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this CodePen, can be useful if you want to sticky footer at bottom of page:

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
}
```

https://codepen.io/cbracco/pen/zekgx

Answer (score 0):

The code forces the footer to the bottom of the page.  It also might be possible to do this with `@media`

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box
  /*Required to be in html*/
}

*{
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 6rem;
  min-height: 100%
}

.demo h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

/**
 * Footer Styles
 */

footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #efefef/*Optional*/
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <h1>CSS “Always on the bottom” Footer</h1>

  <p>I often find myself designing a website where the footer must rest at the bottom of the page, even if the content above it is too short to push it to the bottom of the viewport naturally.</p>
  <p>However, if the content is taller than the user’s viewport, then the footer should disappear from view as it would normally, resting at the bottom of the page (not fixed to the viewport).</p>

  <p>If you know the height of the footer, then you should set it explicitly, and set the bottom padding of the footer’s parent element to be the same value (or larger if you want some spacing).</p>

  <p>This is to prevent the footer from overlapping the content above it, since it is being removed from the document flow with <code>position: absolute;</code>.</p>
</div>

<footer>This footer will always be positioned at the bottom of the page, but <strong>not fixed</strong>.</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is using the display flex property to your container.

Then, set a flex: 1 to your main content section so it take up the max space he can.
Your footer will be at the bottom each time.

Working fiddle:

```css
html {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.one {
  background-color: springgreen;
}

.two {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.three {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  header
</div>
<div class="two">
  content
</div>
<div class="three">
  footer
</div>
```